# Firebase UI delegate method is not called after phone verification is complete

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am trying to implement FIrebase UI phone number authentication, but the delegate method is not called after the phone number is verified. Any reason why?

```
 class Login: UIViewController, FUIAuthDelegate {
   let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()

   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    let phoneProvider = FUIPhoneAuth(authUI: authUI!)
   authUI!.isSignInWithEmailHidden = true
   authUI!.providers = [phoneProvider]
   phoneProvider.signIn(withPresenting: self, phoneNumber: nil)
 }



 //this method does not work either... it is not called
   func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith authDataResult: AuthDataResult?, error: Error?) {

    print("user is \(authDataResult!.user.email)")
    print("err is \(error?.localizedDescription)")
    guard error == nil else {
        print(error)
        return
    }
}


  }
```

Comment: Make sure to add the delegate on top of your class. For example in AppDelegate
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, FUIAuthDelegate {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten to assign self as the delegate to  `authUI`

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

 authUI?.delegate = self
  let phoneProvider = FUIPhoneAuth(authUI: authUI!)
  authUI!.isSignInWithEmailHidden = true
  authUI!.providers = [phoneProvider]
  phoneProvider.signIn(withPresenting: self, phoneNumber: nil)
}
```